# How to check if entities have the same position

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Im making a Snake Game using Armor Stands on the positions of table game and for the body of the snake. I want to check when the the Armor Stand `{Tags:["head"]}` of the snake has the same position of an Armor Stand `{Tags:["food"]}` of a food.
(1.16 Version)

[image]

(The others Armor Stands are invisible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I already know two ways to do that.

**1. Testfor:**

The testfor of 1.12 can be rewrited as, for 1.16:

```
execute at @e[tag=food] if @e[tag=head,distance=..0.5] run tellraw @a "Same Position Check"
```

**2. Execute Store:**

```
execute store result score @e[tag=head] X run data get entity @e[tag=head] Pos[0]; for X coordinate

execute store result score @e[tag=head] Y run data get entity @e[tag=head] Pos[1]; for Y coordinate

execute store result score @e[tag=head] Z run data get entity @e[tag=head] Pos[2]; for Z coordinate
```

---

```
execute store result score @e[tag=food] X run data get entity @e[tag=food] Pos[0]; for X coordinate

execute store result score @e[tag=food] Y run data get entity @e[tag=food] Pos[1]; for Y coordinate

execute store result score @e[tag=food] Z run data get entity @e[tag=food] Pos[2]; for Z coordinate
```

And then, test the scoreboards scores of the coordinates X,Y and Z:

```
execute if score @e[tag=head] X = @e[tag=food] X if score @e[tag=head] Y = @e[tag=food] Y if score @e[tag=head] Z = @e[tag=food] Z run tellraw @a "Same Position Check"
```

Answer (score 1):

## How

Check if the other armor stand is within distance 0.5.

## Selector

```
@e[name=“Example”,distance=..0.5]
```

## Testfor

### 1.13+

```
/execute if @e[name=“Example”,distance=..0.5]
```

### 1.12-

```
/testfor @e[name=“Example”,distance=..0.5]
```

Comment: If anyone knows then could they add a 1.13+ i didn't know selectors even changed in 1.13